# Dependency Property and Binding Error

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding

After hours of searching, I come for your help :

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Test'
>   property not found on 'object'

I couldn't found where my binding error was...

In my MainWindow I have :

```
<Exec:PriceView Price="{Binding Test}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"/>
```

On my TextBlock, the Binding with the Test property is perfectly working.

But for my PriceView control, it's not.

**PriceView.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Arial"/>
</StackPanel>
```

**PriceView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class PriceView : UserControl
{
    public PriceView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    #region Dependency Property
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PriceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Price", typeof(float), typeof(PriceView));

    public float Price
    {
        get { return (float)GetValue(PriceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PriceProperty, value); }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? 
Is this coming from my Dependency Properrty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the remark of @H.B I found the answer :

**Never set the DataContext on UserControls**

*MainWindow.xaml :*

```
<Exec:PriceView Price="{Binding Test}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"/>
```

*PriceView.xaml :*

```
<StackPanel x:name="root"> 
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="26" FontFamily="Arial"/> 
</StackPanel>
```

*PriceView.xaml.cs :*

```
this.root.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: Correction: never set the DataContext of the view when using Dependency Properties.

Comment: Why not? I've successfuly used both at the same time. You only need to understand that when you set the DataContext, your other bindings on the same level use the same context, unless you specify a different source using RelativeSource or ElementName.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is in essence, this:

```
<Exec:PriceView Price="{Binding Test}"
                DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test}"/>
```

It should be apparent why one binding works while the other does not.

Rule of thumb: Never set the `DataContext` on `UserControls`.

Comment: Did not work. I still have the same error. I really do not understand why the binding works on the TextBlock Control and not on the PriceView control.